# Render issue when I learning three.js by the examples

Tags: three.js

Description of the problem

After I had cloned the three.js repository,I watch the canvas_camera_orthographic.html，I saw the scene discribed in the link:
[three.js issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11673),sorry for that I can't upload image

Three.js version

- [x] 0.86.0
- [ ] r85
- [ ] ...

Browser

- [] All of them
- [x] Chrome
- [ ] Firefox
- [ ] Internet Explorer

OS

- [ ] All of them
- [ ] Windows
- [x] macOS
- [ ] Linux
- [ ] Android
- [ ] iOS

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=orth#canvas_camera_orthographic)?

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the CanvasRenderer. Try to modify the example and use the WebGLRenderer instead to see this example working just fine.